# Register Partial in Handlebars

Tags: c#, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have a default.hbs file from which a PDF is generated at the end.

Now we need this document for different tenants, whereby the content only changes in one div. Everything else remains the same.

I have now thought that I can implement this, for example, with the partials of Handlebars, so that I have the default hbs file and can then change the div depending on the tenant.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{Title}}</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div>{{SomeStuff}}</div>
  <br>
  <div>
    {{> tenantDiv}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I would compile it like this:

Company 1

```
string tenant1Template =
    _templates.GetTemplate("Default");

string partialSourceCompany1 =
    @"<strong>Company ABC</strong>";

Handlebars.RegisterTemplate("tenantDiv", partialSourceCompany1);

_templateCache.Add(
    "Company1",
    Handlebars.Compile(tenant1Template));
```

Company 2

```
string tenant2Template =
    _templates.GetTemplate("Default");

string partialSourceCompany2 =
    @"<strong>Company ZXY</strong>";

Handlebars.RegisterTemplate("tenantDiv", partialSourceCompany2);

_templateCache.Add(
    "Company2",
    Handlebars.Compile(tenant2Template));
```

When generating the PDF, I know which company it is and then call up either Company1 or Company2.

But somehow it is not working like this... Is there anything I need to look out for? Or is this not the way how that can be solved? Or is there a better solution for this?

Comment: What part of this is not working? What result are you getting?

Comment: I would like to change the tenantDiv on the fly. So when tenant A genearate this pdf it should add the div for tenant A and if tenant b it should replace it with the div from tenant B... I would like to avoid having both divs in the main document and then having to use an if to see if it is tenant A or B...